# Doxygen: Moving a static variable documentation inside a function

Tags: c++, doxygen

Consider this code:

```
#include <string>

namespace MyNamespace
{

/** \brief Error Class */
class Error
{
public :
    /** \brief Constructor */
    Error ( int in_code, const std::string& in_message );
    ...
};

/** \brief Successfull result */
static Error SUCCESS(                                   0, "Success. " );
/** \brief Error of unknown kind, used internally only to identify a pending result */
static Error ERROR_UNKNOWN(                             1, "Unknown Error. " );
...

};
```

MyNameSpace is already part of a doxygen group. When I generate the documentation, I get:

- One page for `Error` class description
- `SUCCESS` and `ERROR_UNKNOWN` are "Functions" (wierd!) in the `MyNamespace` page

**How can I tag `SUCCESS` and `ERROR_UNKNOWN` to appear in the `Error` class description page?**

Note: I can't define a new group and put both in, as my group list is frozen (we want one group per library). "Hidden" group could be solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, the best "solution" I could find was to use `\memberof`.

This:

```
/** \memberof Error @{ */

/** \brief Successfull result */
static Error SUCCESS(                                   0, "Success. " );
/** \brief Error of unknown kind, used internally only to identify a pending result */
static Error ERROR_UNKNOWN(                             1, "Unknown Error. " );
...

/** @} */
```

Will move `SUCCESS` and `ERROR_UNKNOWN` under "Static Public Member Functions" of `Error` class description. Which is not very nice as they are then mixed with other true static public member functions. But adding a `\name` tag as well...

```
/** \memberof Error @{ */
/** \name Error values: */

/** \brief Successfull result */
static Error SUCCESS(                                   0, "Success. " );
/** \brief Error of unknown kind, used internally only to identify a pending result */
static Error ERROR_UNKNOWN(                             1, "Unknown Error. " );
...

/** @} */
```

Will move `SUCCESS` and `ERROR_UNKNOWN` in a "Error values" section under "Related Functions" of `Error` class description, with a nice Note reporting `(Note that these are not member functions.)`....which is definitely acceptable...

Answer (score 0):

In the code, `SUCCESS` and `ERROR_UNKNOWN` are ***not*** part of the `Error` class, and so the generated documentation is correct (the problem of "function" aside).

Trying to make doxygen show them as part of the Error class is very misleading, as the documentation and the code are now in contradiction.

If you really want `SUCCESS` to be part of the `Error` class, make it so in the code.

Or, and this is probably the intent, in the documentation for the `Error` class, add a comment like `@see SUCCESS`, `@see ERROR_UNKNOWN`.

This will generate "See also" comments pointing to the documentation for these items.

Comment: @see is not doable as there's at least 40 different static `Error`objects available. I know the generated doc is correct, and I also know those static objects should be part of the class instead of being global, but I can't change that now...The solution I wrote is not too bad, as the doc mentions that "these are not member functions."...